# My daemon is unregistered from launchd on logout/login

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd

I create a plist that looks like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">
<!-- My version "1.2.3" -->
<plist version=\"1.0\">
<dict>
<key>Disabled</key>
<false/>
<key>Label</key>
<string>MyPlistName</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>MyDaemonBinPath</string>
<string>-log</string>
<string>MyLogLevel</string>
<string>-launchd</string>
</array>
<key>Sockets</key>
<dict>
<key>Listeners</key>
<dict>
<key>SockFamily</key>
<string>Unix</string>
<key>SockPathMode</key>
<integer>438</integer>
<key>SockPathName</key>
<string>MySocketName</string>
</dict>
</dict>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>MySTDERRLogPath</string>
<key>WaitForDebugger</key>
<false/>
<key>inetdCompatibility</key>
<dict>
<key>Wait</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I place it in /Library/LaunchDaemons

I then run the command:

```
/bin/launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/MyPlistName.plist
/bin/launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/MyPlistName.plist
```

My daemon does launch when I connect to the socket specified in the plist and when I type:

```
launchctl list
```

The daemon is registered but when I log out and log back in and ask for the list again, it's no longer registered and I can't launch my daemon by connecting to the socket

Is there some special permissions I need to be setting on the plist or the daemon to get this to persist between sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your `/var/log/system.log` for errors? Regular plists in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` are run as root on boot-up. You might want to check `sudo launchctl list` to see whether they run. If not, you might need to change the ownership / read+write attributes of the plists to match root. Finally, you could include the following to improve logging:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/logs/launchd_myprogram_stderr.log</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>        
  <string>/logs/launchd_myprogram_stdout.log</string>
```

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked at the issue in some time but when I do I'll give that a try.

Comment: @cppguy did this do the trick? If so, can we "close" or rate this Q&A post?